# Laravel Unique Form Validation

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having a weird problem, using Laravel 5.3

Here's a small snippet of my validation

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'item_rows.*.imei' => 'unique:t_inventory_imei,imei_barcode,NULL,id,status,'."A",
        'item_rows.*.quantity' => 'required|numeric|not_in:0',
        'item_rows.*.cost_price' => 'required|numeric|not_in:0',
        'item_rows.*.id_inventory' => 'required|numeric|not_in:0',
        'item_rows.*.id_branch' => 'required|numeric|not_in:0',
        'item_rows.*.id_branch_location' => 'required|numeric|not_in:0',
        'ref_document_no' => 'required',
        'ref_doc_date' => 'required|date',
      ]);
```

Problem comes when `unique:t_inventory_imei,imei_barcode,NULL,id,status,`."A" this rule is available.

This rule doesn't seem to be validated, it will effect the last rule to be validation error, say returning 
`{"message":"validation_fail","validation_error":{"currentRule":"date"}}`

If I remove the last row, it will cascade up and so on
`{"message":"validation_fail","validation_error":{"currentRule":"required"}}`

If I remove every rule leaving only the first unique rule, the validation works, it is able to detect unique row with rule status A.

Is this a bug from Laravel or is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: If it is `null, id`, should it not then be `A, status`? I.e. `value, column` for ignoring values.

Comment: I'm just re-reading the documentation; you want `t_inventory_imei.imei_barcode` to be unique on new entries (`null, id`) and only where `status = 'A'`, right?

Comment: @TimLewis Yes you are correct, barcode should be unique when status = 'A'